# cannon-es crashes whenever there is a collision between Convex polyhedrons

Tags: javascript, three.js, cannon.js

I am trying to implement a dice roller in three js and cannon-es.
It works perfectly fine if I have only one dice. It rolls against the ground plane in a reasonable way.

When I add another dice it also works fine against the ground plane, but it completely breaks down and crashes the simulation as soon as the two `CANNON.ConvexPolyhedron` objects collide.

The error I am getting spammed with after the collision is this

```
cannon-es.js:920 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'x')
    at Vec3.copy (cannon-es.js:920:21)
    at ConvexPolyhedron.clipFaceAgainstHull (cannon-es.js:2662:24)
    at ConvexPolyhedron.clipAgainstHull (cannon-es.js:2404:12)
    at Narrowphase.convexConvex (cannon-es.js:10916:10)
    at Narrowphase.getContacts (cannon-es.js:10608:33)
    at World.internalStep (cannon-es.js:12649:22)
    at World.step (cannon-es.js:12515:12)
    at updatePhysics (rolling.svelte:154:11)
    at animate (rolling.svelte:142:5)
```

I am using a STL loader from three js to load a stl file of a twenty sided dice, and then I am creating a cannon body from that like this

```
  function createConvexHull(mesh: THREE.Mesh) {
    const position = mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array
    const points: CANNON.Vec3[] = []
    const faces: number[][] = []
    for (let i = 0; i < position.length; i += 3) {
      points.push(new CANNON.Vec3(position[i], position[i + 1], position[i + 2]))
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < position.length / 3; i += 3) {
      faces.push([i, i + 1, i + 2])
    }
    const convexGeometry = new CANNON.ConvexPolyhedron({
      vertices: points,
      faces: faces
    })
    const body = new CANNON.Body({ mass: 1 })
    body.addShape(convexGeometry)
    return body
  }
```

I have little to no idea what is going wrong, as the error message is not saying much, but I've tried computing vertex normals on the ThreeJS mesh, which did nothing.

I've also tried merging verticies as I read that others have had issues with that (merged before creating the cannon body)

```
geometry = BufferGeometryUtils.mergeVertices(geometry, 0.01)
```

but again, it did nothing

Answer (score 1):

Convex polyhedron never behaved correctly for me with more complex shapes. To fix this, I created a Python script with blender that parses the boxes in a collection, which you should name "Colliders," then it will print out json format text in the console, and using that json file I parse it and generate the proper box colliders in my game.

Here is the blender python script:

```py
import bpy
import math

collection = bpy.data.collections.get("Colliders")

# Get all objects in the scene
all_objects = collection.objects

# Count meshes for formatting
meshCount = 0
for obj in all_objects:
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        meshCount += 1

# Print mesh information using ID counter
objectID = 0

print("{")

for obj in all_objects:
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        print("    \"box_" + str(objectID) + "\":{")
        
        # Position
        position = obj.location
        print("        \"position\":{")
        print("            \"x\":" + str(position.x) + ",")
        print("            \"y\":" + str(position.y) + ",")
        print("            \"z\":" + str(position.z))
        print("         },")
        
        # Scale
        scale = obj.scale
        print("        \"scale\":{")
        print("            \"x\":" + str(scale.x) + ",")
        print("            \"y\":" + str(scale.y) + ",")
        print("            \"z\":" + str(scale.z))
        print("         },")
        
        # Rotation (Euler)
        rotation = obj.rotation_euler
        print("        \"rotation\":{")
        print("            \"x\":" + str(math.degrees(rotation.x)) + ",")
        print("            \"y\":" + str(math.degrees(rotation.y)) + ",")
        print("            \"z\":" + str(math.degrees(rotation.z)))
        print("         }")
        if(objectID != meshCount - 1):
            print("    },\n")
        else:
            print("    }")
        
        objectID += 1
        
print("}")
```

That will generate the json text. Copy that from your console, paste it in a .json file, and parse it like so in a js file with cannon:

```js
/*
 * Creating the level collision geometry
 */
async function GenerateLevelColliders(){
    
    // RigidBody
    levelRigidbody = new CANNON.Body({
        type: CANNON.Body.STATIC
    });

    // Parse the JSON file
    await fetch("levelColliders/level_" + currentLevel + ".json")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        let boxID = 0;
        
        for (let boxKey in data) {
            if(data.hasOwnProperty(boxKey)){
                const box = data[boxKey];
                const position = box.position;
                const scale = box.scale;
                const rotation = box.rotation;

                let boxShape = new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(scale.x, scale.y, scale.z));

                // Set the last box as the "checkpoint"
                if(boxID == Object.keys(data).length - 1){
                    // Create a specific body for final shape
                    levelEndRigidbody = new CANNON.Body({
                        type: CANNON.Body.STATIC
                    });

                    // Add its box
                    levelEndRigidbody.addShape(
                        boxShape,
                        new CANNON.Vec3(position.x , position.z, -position.y), // ~ Y is up in blender
                        EulerToQuaternion(rotation.x + 90, rotation.z, -rotation.y)
                    );

                } else {
                    // Add each other box given position, scale and rotation
                    levelRigidbody.addShape(
                        boxShape,
                        new CANNON.Vec3(position.x , position.z, -position.y), // ~ Y is up in blender
                        EulerToQuaternion(rotation.x + 90, rotation.z, -rotation.y)
                    );
                }
                boxID += 1;
            }
        }   
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error parsing JSON file:', error);
    });

    // Add the bodies
    PhysicsWorld.addBody(levelRigidbody);
    PhysicsWorld.addBody(levelEndRigidbody);

    console.log("Finished loading: levelColliders/level_" + currentLevel + ".json ☑");
}
```

Keep in mind you must:

- Run blender directly in order to see console output ( https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/where-does-console-output-go )
- Generate 1 box in blender per collider and **do not apply transforms**
- Name your collection in blender "Colliders"

Hope this is helpful for game devs building larger levels with a bunch of colliders. The only downside to this is your colliders will use only boxes as primitives, but I'm sure this pipeline can be applied to spheres, and even tris.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing, but you may try defining the normals

`new ConvexPolyhedron({ vertices, faces, normals });`

I experienced weird behaviors with convex shape collisions (not errors, but like launching one of the colliding objects into the void), that I could resolve by re calculating the normal vectors

https://github.com/tomo0613/offroadJS_v2/blob/355b6aabf0446deefffba6d60e24a257836916ea/src/mapModules/baseMapElementComponents.ts#L137